# Adding a value to an observable with map

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I'm using Angular 6, HttpClient and Rxjs6. I'm trying to add a property with map but I get `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'`.

```
public onSelectName = $event => {
    this.nameTable$ = this.apiNamesService
        .getNamesById($event.item.id)
        .pipe(map(res => (res.id = $event.item.id)));
};
```

The `res.id` is causing the issue. I have tried casting to any which gives me another error `Cannot find name 'res'`

The apiNamesService looks something like this:

```
public getNamesById = id => this.http.get(`/api/etc/${id}`)
```

Comment: It depends on what type `getNamesById` returns

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the value via the array operator and string.

```
res['id'] = $event.item.id
```

This by-passes the TypeScript property checking at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the object is not your concern, you can simply use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
 public onSelectName = $event => {
        this.nameTable$ = this.apiNamesService
            .getNamesById($event.item.id)
            .pipe(map(res => Object.assign({id: $event.item.id}, res)));
    };
```

This creates a brand new copy of the object, with the extra property `id`, without modifying your original response.